# View full javadoc while browsing autocomplete options in IntelliJ

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea, javadoc

I've always used Eclipse and I'm trying out IntelliJ now. One thing that I really miss is that in eclipse you could read the javadoc for any methods while browsing autocomplete options.

Eclipse:

[image]

IntelliJ:

[image]

Is there a way I can replicate that behavior in IntelliJ?

Comment: You need to show tooltip with documentation by `Ctrl+Q` or on `Mac` `Ctrl+J` and it will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While browsing autocomplete options you can invoke **Q**uick documentation lookup by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd>:

[image]

Also you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> for **P**arameter info (which can be useful sometimes):

[image]

[**IntelliJ IDEA Reference Card**](https://resources.jetbrains.com/storage/products/intellij-idea/docs/IntelliJIDEA_ReferenceCard.pdf) to see all shortcuts

Comment: I knew you could do Ctl + Q on a method I'd already typed out, didn't know you could do it while in the auto complete menu. Perfect!